# Converting TeX from BITS xml structured for section heads section heads

Tags: xslt, latex

I am trying to convert the tex file from the xml (BITS structure), i am have the issue for section heads, when section heads in the `<boxed-text>`, the hierarchy is not printing correctly
for example, `<boxed-text>` is in 3rd level section, and the `<boxed-text>` have section heads
those section heads are treated as next level of 3rd level section (ie., 4th level head), it should be treated as 1st level head in the box-text and so on only in the `<boxed-text>`

I need the output like below, but i am getting the wrong output, how to get the desired output? please suggest.

```
\section*{First Level Head}

Text under Head

\subsection*{Second Level Head}

\subsubsection*{Third Level Head}

Text under Head
\begin{annotebox}
Boxed TeXT Astrophysical S factor

\section{Box Level 1 head }

\subsection{Box Level 2 head}

The powers.......

\subsubsection{Box Level 3 head}

The powers......

\paragraph{Box Level 4 head}

.....

\subsection{Box Level 4 head}
\end{annotebox}


Text under Boxed TeXT

\paragraph*{4th Level Head}
```

i am using the below xsl structure to convert the file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="2.0" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"  use-character-maps="latex"/>

<xsl:template match="title">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="parent::sec"><!--Section Head-->
                        <xsl:if test="parent::sec/label!=''">
                                <xsl:value-of select="if(ancestor::sec[5]) then '\def\thesubparagraph{' else if(ancestor::sec[4]) then '\def\theparagraph{' else if(ancestor::sec[3]) then '\def\thesubsubsection{' else if(ancestor::sec[2]) then '\def\thesubsection{' else if(ancestor::sec[1]) then '\def\thesection{' else ''" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="parent::sec/label"/>
                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">}&#10;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="if(ancestor::sec[5])
                                                      then (if(parent::sec/label!='') then '\subparagraph{' else '\subparagraph*{')
                                              else if(ancestor::sec[4])
                                                        then (if(parent::sec/label!='') then '\paragraph{' else '\paragraph*{')
                                                   else if(ancestor::sec[3])
                                                             then (if(parent::sec/label!='') then '\subsubsection{' else '\subsubsection*{')
                                                        else if(ancestor::sec[2])
                                                                   then (if(parent::sec/label!='') then '\subsection{' else '\subsection*{')
                                                              else if(ancestor::sec[1])
                                                                         then (if(parent::sec/label!='') then '\section{' else '\section*{')
                                                                    else ''" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates/>
                      <xsl:value-of select="if(ancestor::sec[5]) then '}&#10;' else if(ancestor::sec[4]) then '}&#10;' else if(ancestor::sec[3]) then '}&#10;' else if(ancestor::sec[2]) then '}&#10;' else if(ancestor::sec[1]) then '}&#10;' else ''" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my MWE is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="eng">
<book-body>
<book-part book-part-type="chapter" id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002">
<book-part-meta>
<book-part-id book-part-id-type="doi">10.1093/9876543212345.003.0002</book-part-id>
<title-group id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002-title-group-001">
<label>8</label>
<title>Germany</title>
<subtitle>Chapter subtitle</subtitle>
</title-group>
</book-part-meta>
<body>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-001-sec-003">
<title>First Level Head</title>
<p>Text under Head</p>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-001-sec-003">
<title>Second Level Head</title>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-001-sec-003">
<title>Third Level Head</title>
<p>Text under Head</p>
<boxed-text content-type="annotation" id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002-boxed-text-002">
<p>Boxed TeXT Astrophysical S factor</p>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002-sec-0006">
<label>1</label><title>Box Level 1 head </title>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002-sec-0007">
<label>1.1</label><title>Box Level 2 head</title>
<p>The powers and procedures in this Code must be used fairly, responsibly, with respect for the people to whom they apply and without unlawful 
discrimination</p>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002-sec-0007">
<label>1.1.1</label><title>Box Level 3 head</title>
<p>The powers and procedures in this Code must be used fairly, responsibly, with respect for the people to whom they apply and without unlawful 
discrimination</p>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002-sec-0008">
<label>1.1.1.1</label><title>Box Level 4 head</title>
<p>All persons in custody must be dealt with expeditiously, and released as soon as the need for detention no longer applies.Use Quote to identify short prose 
quotes of material.</p>
<p>The Quote typecode can include a Source typecode for attribution, but otherwise won&#x0027;t have much structure. For</p>
<p>longer structured extracts use the Extract code.</p>
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-002-sec-0006">
<label>1</label><title>Box Level 1 head </title>
<p>Boxed TeXT Astrophysical S factor</p>
</sec>
</sec>
</boxed-text>
<p>Text under Boxed TeXT</p>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-001-sec-003">
<title>4th Level Head</title>
<p>Text under Head</p>
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
</sec>
<sec id="isbn-9876543212345-book-part-001-sec-003">
<title>First Level Head</title>
<p>Text under Head</p>
</sec>
</body>
</book-part>
</book-body>
</book>
```

Comment: The structure seems recursively nested, the XSLT says `version="2.0"`, so perhaps recursive grouping helps. Are you really using an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9 or 10?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am suing saxon 9

Comment: If you only want to create `subsection`s based only on the `block-text` ancestor then I understand the desired output `\subsubsection{Box Level 3 head}` but why is it followed by `\subsection{Box Level 4 head}` and not by `\subsubsubsection*{Box Level 4 head}`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:mode on-multiple-match="use-last"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="book//body/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="sec/label"/>

  <xsl:template match="sec/title">\{string-join((1 to count(ancestor::sec) - 1)!'sub', '')}section*{{{.}}}</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sec[label]/title">\{string-join((1 to count(ancestor::sec) - 1)!'sub', '')}section{{{.}}}</xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="sec/sec/sec/sec/title">\paragraph*{{{.}}}</xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="sec/sec/sec/sec[label]/title">\paragraph{{{.}}}</xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:template match="boxed-text" expand-text="no">\begin{annotebox}<xsl:apply-templates/>\end{annotebox}</xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="boxed-text//sec/title">\{string-join((1 to count(ancestor::sec[not(descendant::boxed-text)]) - 1)!'sub', '')}section*{{{.}}}</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="boxed-text//sec[label]/title">\{string-join((1 to count(ancestor::sec[not(descendant::boxed-text)]) - 1)!'sub', '')}section{{{.}}}</xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="boxed-text/sec/sec/sec/sec/title">\paragraph{{{.}}}</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="boxed-text//sec/sec/sec/sec[label]/title">\paragraph*{{{.}}}</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs

```
\section*{First Level Head}
Text under Head

\subsection*{Second Level Head}

\subsubsection*{Third Level Head}
Text under Head
\begin{annotebox}
Boxed TeXT Astrophysical S factor

\section{Box Level 1 head }

\subsection{Box Level 2 head}
The powers and procedures in this Code must be used fairly, responsibly, with respect for the people to whom they apply and without unlawful 
discrimination

\subsubsection{Box Level 3 head}
The powers and procedures in this Code must be used fairly, responsibly, with respect for the people to whom they apply and without unlawful 
discrimination

\paragraph*{Box Level 4 head}
All persons in custody must be dealt with expeditiously, and released as soon as the need for detention no longer applies.Use Quote to identify short prose 
quotes of material.
The Quote typecode can include a Source typecode for attribution, but otherwise won't have much structure. For
longer structured extracts use the Extract code.




\subsection{Box Level 1 head }
Boxed TeXT Astrophysical S factor


\end{annotebox}
Text under Boxed TeXT

\paragraph*{4th Level Head}
Text under Head





\section*{First Level Head}
Text under Head
```